# Can I search the RapidShare-like servers for certain files?

Tags: search, search-engines, online-storage

RapidShare's answer to that question is:

> No, RapidShare protects the privacy of
>   its users. Only the person storing a
>   file on RapidShare receives the
>   download link. That person can decide
>   who should have access to the link. A
>   file can only be downloaded if the
>   download link details are known.

Isn't it possible to search RapidShare using Google's "site:" parameter? For example:

```
"martial arts" site:rapidshare.com
```

fetches some results from rapidshare servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's a](http://www.bashbosh.com/28-effective-rapidshare-search-engines/) blog post mentioning *28* RapidShare search engines including

1. [MegaDownload](http://megadownload.net/)
2. [RapidZilla](http://rapidzilla.net/)
3. [Rapidshare searcher](http://www.rapidshare-searcher.com/)
4. [Rapidshare Index](http://www.rapidshareindex.com/)
5. [RS Find](http://www.rsfind.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results from [Filestube](http://www.filestube.com/) in the past.